# Is it possible tu use a UNION sql in agiletoolkit?

Tags: atk4

I want to combine to tables: the sql is:

```
select name, extract(DAY from fechaNacimiento) from alumno
union
select name,extract(DAY from fechaNacimiento) from asesor
```

Is it possible to use that query in a dsql() or dq() statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am author of Agile Toolkit and UnionModel implementation is now available as a separate module for [Agile Data](https://github.com/atk4/data).

http://www.agiletoolkit.org/data/extensions/report

With the extension, assuming you have models for "Alumno" and "Asesor" for which fields name/day are defined to produce above queries, you can construct a Union Model based on domain logic:

```
$union = new \atk4\report\UnionModel($db);
$union->addNestedModel(new Model_Alumno());
$union->addNestedModel(new Model_Asesor());
$union->addField('name');
$union->addField('day');
```

Resulting model will be read-only but can be fully used anywhere, will support grouping, conditions, limits and will query only fields necessary.

---

Solution without using "Reporting Extension" would involve aligning queries from nested models manually and putting them inside Expression:

```
$expr = new \atk4\dsql\Expression(
    "select ... from ([] union [])",
    [
        $m1->action('select', [$fields]), 
        $m2->action('select', [$fields]),
    ]
);
```

Support for versions prior to 4.4 are now considered obsolete.

Comment: I went for the quickfix, to be honest I don't know what to do with the other way, thanks for your time, and Thank you for ATK,is awesome!